# Debug Python call in Powershell

Tags: python, powershell, visual-studio-2015

I'm currently working on a project in Python and Powershell.  I've set up Visual Studio 2015 as the environment for development. I have tools for Powershell and Python installed.

The problem is that it is very hard to debug information being passed between Python and Powershell.  Is there a way to step between platforms while debugging?

Currently, when I run a python script from Powershell, I get no feed back from Python.  I can only see what gets passed back to Powershell.

Powershell Code Example:

```
Try
{
    $file_fullName = & python $pythonScript $profile_id $report_id $fileOutputPath
}
Catch
{
    $msg = command 2>&1
    Write-Host $_.Exception.Message
    Write-Host $_.Exception.ItemName
    Write-Host $_.Exception.Message
    Write-Host $msg
```

Comment: What do you mean? If you run `$var = & python some_python_file.py`, var should contain the result of running your Python program (i.e. what Python writes to stdout). Ideally you could show us a minimal python program and also state what you expect the output to be in powershell.

Comment: @Alex Alifmoff - I'm not sure this is a code question, vs a general environment question.  It's not about the execution, so much as how do I debug the two together?  See if I run python from Powershell I get no feed back on the python. ie, I can't step through the code, I can't check locals, print statements don't output anywhere, etc.  Its like Powershell executes the python silently in the background and I can't get any feed back on the actual execution.  This makes it very hard to find errors.

Comment: Why can't you debug the Python in a Python development environment? What I was trying to say in my original comment was if you run "$var = & python -c print('This is the contents of var')", var will contain "This is the contents of var". Thus, print statements from your Python code are contained in $file_fullName in your example.

Comment: 1) $file_fullName contains information returned explicitly by my python function, no?  I don't believe it will contain intermediary information about a particular execution - such as print or debug statements.  2).  I can do some development in a python environment, but since information is constantly passed back and forth constantly in very long scripts it is epic-ly slow.

Comment: I do not believe you are correct. $file_fullName in this case will contain whatever your script writes to stdout. The return value of the script is stored in $LASTEXITCODE. Try it out yourself. `$var = python -c print("put some text here"); exit(-101)`. Then examine $var and $LASTEXITCODE. You can also pipe stderr to stdout when you call into Python using `2>&1`

Comment: @AlexAlifimoff is there a good free py IDE that has good debugging? If not, what's the best paid option? unfortunately it seems like powershell doesn't have any good options (eg GDB)